# Как убрать белый отступ справа на мобильном, который появляется при горизонтальном скролле?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Делаю портфолио на шаблоне https://scripteden.com/previews/Clean/ и в самом шаблоне есть проблема - на мобильном появляется отступ при горизонтальном скролле, изначально его не видно. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть дело? Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ такой же, как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721560/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0)

Причина в некорректном использовании бутсрап – два вложенных .row

Решение:

```
.row.skills {
 margin-right: 0px;
```

}