# как сделать ширину страницы в шаблоне под область просмотра?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Как в этом шаблоне https://scripteden.com/previews/Clean/ сделать ширину страницы под область просмотра?

[Проверка выдает](http://adaptivator.ru/?site=https%3A%2F%2Fscripteden.com%2Fpreviews%2FClean%2F):

Ширина страницы составляет 427 CSS-пикс., а области просмотра – всего 412 CSS-пикс. Эти элементы находятся вне области просмотра:

Элемент

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">My Skills…arvels around.</div>
```

находится вне области просмотра.

Comment: Если лень все адаптировать тогда просто ограничь минимальную ширину html до 427 , либо можно менять на ходу мета viewpoint

Comment: прошу прощение за глупые вопросы, я совсем новичок. после *{min-width: 427px;} адаптивность упала ещё сильнее, с 96/100 до 88/100. проверяю на http://adaptivator.ru/ я что-то не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить:

```
.row.skills {
     margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, сработало!

Comment: Отлично. Причина там в некорректном использовании бутсрап – два вложенных .row